# Problema para fazer requisição via restTemplate

Tags: java, api, web-service, rest

Olá Estou desenvolvendo um .jar que consulta o valor de cotação do dollar, através da requisição para um endpoint disponibilizado pelo banco central. Quando faço a requisição via postman o json vem corretamente, mas pelo java usando o restTemplate ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:511) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:623) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:967) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
```

Classe service

```
@Override
    public Map<String,Object> consultaCotacao() {
        boolean ok = false;
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap();

        String filter = setFiltroRequisicao();

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(header);

        ParameterizedTypeReference<CotacaoMoeda> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<CotacaoMoeda>() {
        };

        String endpoint = ConstantsURL.CONSULTA_COTACAO_COMPRA + filter;

        try{
            ResponseEntity<CotacaoMoeda> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint,
                    HttpMethod.GET, request, typeRef);

            CotacaoMoeda cotacaoMoeda = responseEntity.getBody();

            response.put("cotacaoMoeda",cotacaoMoeda);
            response.put("HttpStatus", responseEntity.getStatusCode());

        }catch(Exception e){
            response.put("cotacaoMoeda",null);
            response.put("HttpStatus", 500);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Classe CotaçãoMoeda

```
@Data
public class CotacaoMoeda {

    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = Value.class)
    private Value value;

}
```

Classe Value

```
@Data
public class Value {

   private BigDecimal cotacaoCompra;

}
```

Json retorno

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://was-p.bcnet.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata$metadata#_CotacaoDolarDia(cotacaoCompra)",
    "value": [
        {
            "cotacaoCompra": 5.36200
        }
    ]
}
```

Obs: Já tentei colocar no retorno do restTemplate como List , mas não deu certo. Tbm tentei colocar na classe CotacaoMoeda o atributo value como list, mas também não foi

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema alterando a versão da dependência spring-web para 5.2.9.RELEASE, do projeto. Logo após ele começou a devolver o objeto ResponseEntity corretamente

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```